# Bugs w/ SMS w/ Iphones

Tags: sms, 5.0-lollipop, stock-android, ios, nexus-6

When in a group chat with iphone users I often get:

- Messages that are received late
- Messages that send late
- Error messages stating a have received a "multimedia message" from one
  member of the group chat, when no message was sent

I understand that imessage and iphones don't play nice in general. But are there any steps that I can take to reduce these issues. Any advice at all?

(Using Nexus 6, but have experienced this problem on the 5 and Galaxy Nexus. All T-mobile.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems when iphone owners deactvate imessage you can send and receive sms to/from them without problems. It seems lollipop cannot read sms because it seems an imessage and not a sms. A clear bug.